# android is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: android, windows, ant, command-line

So I'm having the same issue as this guy in this question

[android' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350692/android-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command#comment14948920_11350726)

But when I changed my PATH variable and added the path to android.bat my cmd still does gives

```
'android' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

My PATH looks like this

```
D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04\bin;D:\BossGrand\Programing\Ant\apache-ant-1.8.4\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;D:\Program Files\Android\tools
```

and I made sure android.bat is inside D:\Program Files\Android\tools

I know this because when I go to this directory I can use the android update project command just fine

Does anyone know why I still can't use the android command?

Comment: Have you closed your command window and opened a new one? Only command windows opened after the change to PATH will get the update PATH.

Comment: ang also you need to add platform-tools in your environment variables also. coz adb had moved.

Answer (score 1):

Use the command prompt with admin .It work for me : )

Answer (score 0):

You might have installed Cygwin as part of the SDK. I had the same problem "android.bat is not recognized as an internal or external command". So, Uninstall the Cygwin and try again (you might not able to uninstall Cygwin, since a mysterious “permission denied” when deleting the Cygwin files by default). You need to own access to this mysterious Cygwin files by doing

Take ownership: takeown /r /d y /f cygwin (do this, wherever is your cygwin folder is)

This command takes ownership recursive of the folder, without asking anything and gives Full Access to Everyone recursively in the folder:

icacls cygwin /t /grant Everyone:F And finally, the command which deletes it all and removes Cygwin:

rmdir /s /q cygwin Good bye Cygwin!

Now try again. (This worked for me)

PS: You can always re-install cygwin again. So, nothing wrong giving it a try. Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

you must enter the command with complete arguments

```
android update project -p .
```

be carefull you must enter a dot at the end of command.