# An error occurred during creation of android sub-project because a path is not found

Tags: android, cordova, npm

I'm trying to do `phonegap build android` and I have this message :

```
[phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] adding the Android platform...
   [error] An error occured during creation of android sub-project. Path not found
```

Phonegap is looking for "C:\Documents and Settings\corbg\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.0.0\bin\create". There is nothing under the directory "3.0.0". I installed cordova like this `npm install -g cordova`.

I have the some problem when I run `cordova platform add android`.

Did I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was a problem with my proxy. Cordova create a `.cordova` directory and try to download something on the internet. The download did not work. Next time, it check if there is a `.cordova` directory. It don't try to redownload something because the directory exist and it show the error.

I removed the `.cordova` directory and I solved my problems with proxy. Now, everythings works.

Comment: If I remove the .cordova directory I get a current working directory is not a cordova based project, what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You must to be on the directory of your project to do this command.

Comment: Yes, I was. I had a sudo related issue. Fixed now. Thanks for the reply though!

Comment: Just want you to elaborate on this a Lil bit.. What happens when you build without cordova directory? Won't it throw an error? What problems were you having with the proxy?

Comment: And which cordova directory are you talking about? The one in your Project or the one found in users/ folder of windows 7?

Comment: The directory is on the user folder. The remote site was simply blocked in the proxy.

Comment: Deleting .cordova was a big mistake

Answer (score 11):

In Windows machine you have to delete .cordova directory under
C:\Users\user_name\

Comment: same error came back after it was downloading for a while

Answer (score 8):

I have face the same issue, then i corrected my application path, afterthat it is worked out for me.

If you are using win 7 then add the Android ADK path in
open the mycomputer -> Properties -> Change Settings-> Advanced -> Environment Variable -> User variable for ....-> path
add the Android ADK path here like as following

C:\AndroidDev\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\tools; C:\AndroidDev\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\platform-tools

also add JAVA_HOME and ANT_HOME.
- Abdul Jabbar

Answer (score 6):

Did you set your PATH variable? Sometimes this error occurs in Windows when the PATH variable is not set correctly to access "java" and "ant" exes. If you want to test if they are correctly set, you can simply execute both (from any folder in your command line):

```
> java
```

or

```
> ant
```

and both programs should be found.

Answer (score 3):

What solved the issue for me was having 2 directories on my PATH, the android platform-tools and tools.
In my pc those folders were at
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools

Also make sure you have the following environment variables

- **JAVA_HOME** (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51)
- **ANT_HOME** (C:\Program Files\apache\apache-ant-1.9.3)
- **ANDROID_HOME** (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools)

I removed the .cordova folder under my user folder but I'm not quite sure if that helped as well.

These links may help you

- [An error occured during creation of android sub-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20616893/an-error-occured-during-creation-of-android-sub-project)
- [android' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350692/android-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: Adding those three environment variables worked for me. ...thanks for pointing out @Jonathan

Comment: JAVA_HOME and ANT_HOME worked for me. My Java was set to the JRE. I had to change JAVA_HOME to point to the JDK folder. The tools.jar is only found in JDK and is needed to build with Ant.

Comment: A Stupid typeo!! But thank you for at least reminding me I was stupid!

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem for a different reason. I had an old version of ant (1.7.1). At least version 1.8.2 is needed for the build to work.

Comment: I had the same issue. I had to download latest ant and change ANT_HOME

Answer (score 0):

This is because you haven't installed ANT!
download it from here and install it step by step
https://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html

Then running the last command it will install the dependencies needed.

Answer (score 0):

its either due to improper installation or no installation of ANT or JAVA. But moreover we need to add Android SDk and prepare Android Targets via SDK manager before going through this.