# Phonegap 3.3 cannot add platform

Tags: java, android, windows, cordova

I have upgraded my Phonegap running on Windows 7 to the currently latest version to 3.3.0. I could create a project without any issue but when I try to add a platform say "android" an error occurs. Shown below is the error I get when I run "cordova platform add android" command on command promt on Windows 7. Please help.

```
E:\Dropbox\Development\Android\weatherlk>cordova platform add android

Creating android project...

C:\Users\Teshan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: An error occured during creation of android sub-project.

C:\Users\Teshan\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: An error occurred while listing Android targets
    at C:\Users\Teshan\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\lib\check_
    at _rejected (C:\Users\Teshan\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin
    at C:\Users\Teshan\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\node_modul
    at Promise.when (C:\Users\Teshan\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\Teshan\.cordova\lib\and
752:41)
    at C:\Users\Teshan\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\node_modul
    at flush (C:\Users\Teshan\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\nod
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)

    at C:\Users\Teshan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\src\plat
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:641:7)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:735:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:802:5)
```

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly this problem today. Turned out I had white space in the path variable for \android-sdk\tools (in windows 7 environment variables). Check the android batch file runs, ie type android in a command prompt in any directory, and also adb for the platform-tools path. A similar question is answered here < [An error occured during creation of android sub-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20616893/an-error-occured-during-creation-of-android-sub-project) >.

Comment: typing android in cmd says no such command but typing adb shows a big list. adb works for me.

Comment: As timmacp said, For Cordova command-line tools to work, you need to include the SDK's tools and platform-tools directories in your PATH environment. http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide checkout this guide and follow the steps mentioned under windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a blog about installing it from start to finish with a little more detail than phonegap/cordova docs offer. A lot easier than piecing together the different stack questions: http://www.andrewsavory.com/blog/2013/2517