# you have not accepted the license agreements of the following sdk components [android sdk build-tools 23.0.1]

Tags: android, react-native, sdk, build-tools

I have the next problem, i am tryng to run my app with react-native. can you help me please[image]

Comment: I want to run my app that i write, I am using React native. but I have that Problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Try this way**

**go to the path of ur android-sdk\tools**

`C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools`

**then run below command**

```
.\android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter build-tools-xx.x.x,android-xx,extra-android-m2repository
```

it will install with  accepted the license agreements

according to your problem build-tools-xx.x.x is 23.0.1 and android-xx is 23

Comment: not working for me it says android is not recognized an internal command

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350692/android-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command   did you start command with "./android.."

Answer (score 3):

Open a command prompt, go to your Android SDK folder and execute: sdkmanager.bat --licenses

It will prompt you to accept the licenses you haven't.

PS. Please make a Google search before posting, this has been widely answered.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me (on Windows):

Navigate to: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools`

Right-click `android.bat` and **Open as Administrator**.

You can now manually install and accept the license agreement for **Android SDK Build-tools 23.0.01**.

If it complains about `[Android Support Repository]` or any other package then simply repeat the process for that package. Cheers.