# cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

The official ReactJS documentation suggests to run the following command in the terminal for generating the release APK

```
cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

I get an exception in response to this command:

```
cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

What is an issue?

Answer (score 15):

For Windows you need to use backslash in the original command

```
cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working. simple but took a lot of time.

Comment: in windows you can use only `cd android && gradlew assembleRelease`

Answer (score 4):

As a part of solving this issue for *Windows*, I found that the following steps are required for building React Native from source:

1. Make sure that you have Java jdk, Android SDK and gradle installed and they are accessible as global variables. You can check it by the following command (see more [How to set up the environment variable for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350692/android-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/49091952#49091952)):

   ```
   java -version
   android list target
   gradle -v
   ```
2. it is necessary to set up gradle environment for **root/android/** directory of the project (gradlew.bat executive file and other environment files)

   ```
   gradle init
   ```

   Note: you need to rename or remove build.gradle file before you run gradle init. After you run gradle init, you can return build.gradle back.
3. Create directories and file AndroidManifest.xml as it is shown below

   ```
   root\android\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
   ```
4. AndroidManifest.xml has to have the following minimal content:

   ```
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="myAppName">
     <uses-permission android:name="myAppName" />
     <uses-feature android:name="feature-01" android:required="false" />
   </manifest>
   ```
5. For *Windows* you need to use **backslash** in the original command

   ```
   cd android && .\gradlew assembleRelease
   ```
6. You are going to find the resulted build package by this path:

   ```
   root\android\build\outputs\aar\android-release.aar
   ```

Comment: The `$` commonly refers to a Unix shell... Your error indicates you're running Windows